# CakePHP models derivating from others

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a situation and i'm stuck with it.

I have these models at my application:

`Person`, `Teacher`, `Student`, `Employee`, `Classification`

So I want to add

- `Classification` to `Teacher`, `Student` and `Employee`

I don't want to have classification foreign key at all the tables so i came up with the table person and I have the next relationships:

- Person (without foreign keys)
- Teacher (with person foreign key)
- Student (with person foreign key) Employee(with person foreign key)
- Classification (with person foreign key)

How can i get all the classifications from teachers for example?

What relations I add to the cakephp models?

**Edit:**
Maybe this?

```
 class Classification extends AppModel {
        public $belongsTo = array(
            'Person' => array(
                'className' => 'Person',
                'foreignKey' => 'person_id'
            ),

        );
 }
```

and then

```
class Person extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Teacher' => array(
            'className' => 'Teacher',
            'foreignKey' => 'person_id'
        ),
        'Student' => array(
            'className' => 'Student',
            'foreignKey' => 'person_id'
        ),
        'Employee' => array(
            'className' => 'Employee',
            'foreignKey' => 'person_id'
        ),
    );
}
```

this is correct for the case?

Answer (score 0):

- `Teacher` hasMany `Classification`
- `Student` hasMany `Classification`
- `Employee` hasMany `Classification`

Comment: thanks for the answer but were i put the Person table? I gave this example but there are more relations like classification that i need to add to these 3 entities

Comment: what is the difference between Teacher, Student and Employee? (are there different functions for each of them?) Maybe they are all Persons and they should all be in the same table/model, and have a `type` field.

Comment: No they cant be at the same table because they have different attributes

Comment: How many models do you have? Can you paste the database structure for them?

Comment: my database is very complex. this was just a example because the database isn't about this. is just a similar structure  were I'm stuck.

Comment: so lets say that i dont need the `Person` table how can I add a classification knowing that i came from teacher model? and what foreign key i add to `Classification` table?

Comment: It seems a many-to-many relationship (hasAndBelongsToMany) http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#relationship-types